# QUERY(...) slightly changes datetime values

Tags: google-sheets, floating-point, google-sheets-formula, precision

I've encountered a problem where `QUERY` slightly changes **some** datetime values. Here goes a minimal reproducible example.

A [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2g1ubz_B4cSaG6Y0r22-ciK5uh-ZJlO3SAI34p-mdU) to play with.

- `A:A` has datetime values.
- `B:B` repeats them using `=FILTER(A2:A, SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A), 1, 1, 0))`.
- `C:C` shows row numbers for any values that do not match the original. There is `N/A`, everything matches.
- `D:D` repeats original datetimes with `=QUERY(A2:A,,0)`.
- `E:E` shows row numbers for any values that do not match the original. There is a few.
- `F:F` shows the original values and `G:G` shows the values after the `QUERY` for the non-matching pairs. 10th digit after the dot is different
- `H:H` shows the difference between `F:F` and `G:G`. Always the same: `-0.000000000007276...`

Why is that? Any way to remedy that? Maybe it is a bug in Google Sheets?

P.S.: the data is from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925303/google-sheets-arrayformula-for-maxifs/62369912#62369912) (removed everything except datetimes). I had to use a `FILTER` solution in the answer despite a `QUERY` solution being simpler.

Comment: I found a workaround: I add an extra column and put =N(A2) etc in that column. Then I use the filter and query on that column instead of A.

Answer (score 3):

this behavior is caused by "floating error" of time values where `FILTER` works with values while `QUERY` tries to internally convert it to text string which cases that end / decimal positions of value are cut off - hance the difference between `QUERY` and `FILTER`. in sense of "accuracy" the `FILTER` is more "precise", tho in sense of common sense and casual logic - who cares about time values represented in formatting with 15+ decimal places which is way beyond millisecond scale...

Comment: Who cares... Do you mind giving a try with `QUERY` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925303/google-sheets-arrayformula-for-maxifs/62369912#62369912). `VLOOKUP` won't find some dt in the original column. At least w/o additional modifications.

Comment: hard to guess how and where you wanted to apply QUERY but I checked your proposed VLOOKUP solution and it works great on every row emulating the array of "MAXIF"

Comment: I wanted to use `QUERY({K:K, E:E}, "SELECT Col1, MAX(Col2) GROUP BY Col1", 1)` instead of `SORT({K2:K, E2:E}, 2, False)`. That would've given a smaller range of unique datetimes to search through using `VLOOKUP`. And I actually did, but luckily was not lazy at that moment and checked with the original OP's solution - found that issue as a result.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, it was driving me mad. I have a table with, among other data, a timestamp and an member-ID. In another sheet I use FILTER, MATCH and QUERY to get only the newest row of each member. Because of your explanation I stopped looking for why one member disappeared from the newest-table, and instead made an extra column in the original table: =N(A2) where column A is the timestamp.